# How do I set a path to matplotlib canvas save button

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, save

I want to set a path to matplotlib canvas built in save button. I have no idea how to do this and could not find anything about it. for example, say I have this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
plt.show()
```

I get the following image. when I press the save button it take me to my user root path. I want to set the path, so the save dialog is opened at my specified path.

[image]

I found some code to save canvas using `figure.savefig()` binding to a key ('s') but I want to bind to the build in save button.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# Disable the 's' interactive keybinding
mpl.rcParams['keymap.save'] = ''

def save(event):
    if event.key == 's':
        print('Saved figure')
        event.canvas.figure.savefig('temp.png')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', save)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# Set the path for the save button
path = 'C:\\set\\your\\path\\'
mpl.rcParams['savefig.directory'] = path

# Set the format for the save button
mpl.rcParams['savefig.format'] = 'jpg'

def save(event):
    if event.key == 's':
        print('Saved figure')
        event.canvas.figure.savefig(path)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', save)
plt.show()
```